# Jenkins does not start the testsuite, hangs on open browser

Tags: jenkins, robotframework, selenium2library

Windows 10, Firefox 52, Robot 3.0.1, Selenium 3.4.3, Selenium2Library 1.8.0

When I create a new build in Jenkins the test suite hangs just before opening the browser. The command that I'm using in "Execute Windows batch command" is:

```
powershell.exe "Start-Service 'asd Workflow Manager'"
git reset --hard
git clean -fdx
del geckodriver.log
call robot.bat --variable BASE_URL:zxc/Adress  --variable LOGIN:jenkins --variable PASSWORD:admin@123 --variable BROWSER:firefox--debugfile --exclude Unstable --outputdir .\report Z:\<path_to_tests>\*.robot
copy C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Logs\asd.log .
copy C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1\*.log .
powershell.exe "Stop-Service 'asd Workflow Manager'"
exit 0
```

But when the build is being created it hangs when It starts robot tests:

"
call robot.bat --variable BASE_URL:zxc/Adress  --variable LOGIN:jenkins --variable PASSWORD:admin@123 --variable BROWSER:firefox --debugfile --exclude Unstable --outputdir .\report Z:\path_to_tests\*.robot

.........................

TestNames

........................
"

And nothing happens. My suite setup is:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Selenium2Library   10    10
Library  Process
Library  String
Resource          ../../keywords/keywords.robot
Suite Setup   Open Browser        ${BASE_URL}/ControlPanel.aspx?item=Assign_Roles    ff
Suite Teardown   Logout

*** Variables ***
${BASE_URL}     xcv

*** Test Cases ***
Login
    Log to Console      Hello world
```

If I comment the "Library  Selenium2Library" at least I get an error with that Open browser keyword is not present.

Additionally I used in cmd the same command I use start automated tests on Jenkins and It all worked fine.

call robot.bat --variable BASE_URL:http://127.0.0.1/Adress  --variable LOGIN:jenkins --variable PASSWORD:admin@123 --variable BROWSER:firefox --debugfile --exclude Unstable --outputdir .\report Z:\path_to_tests*.robot

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation it turned out that Jenkins was running without graphic context. probably because it was started from GIT bash. 
The fix is to restart it in the command line.